# How can I format a label or text box to receive currency values using decimal places correctly?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

How can I correctly format a label or text box to receive currency values using decimal places?

I have an Excel spreadsheet that acts as a database with financial values for a series of costs.
From this database, I use an app developed in powerapps which, when accessed, creates a collection of these values and places them in a gallery. When you click on one of the items in the gallery, the app opens an in-depth description of the selected item.
However, values involving financial items do not appear correctly formatted in the corresponding labels.

> For example: the cost value X, in the collection, appears as `2326,385` and I would like it to be formatted in currency type, as `$ 2,326.38`.

> For larger amounts, the problem is more pronounced... for example, `$36,060.50` appears as `36,060,503.00`, using a code similar to the one in example 3.

In the database, the fields are formatted as currency type

None of these options worked correctly, however, I noticed that in values that do not have decimal places after the integer value, the formatting works correctly.

Could you help me with this problem?

I've done the following tests:

```
VarFormType.COST
```

---

```
Text(Round(Value(VarFormType.COST);1);"$0.00";Language())
```

---

```
Text(Round(Value(VarFormType.COST);1);"$#,##,0.00";Language())
```

---

```
Value(VarFormType.COST)
```

Comment: [This](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-do-I-format-a-field-to-look-like-currency/td-p/126995) article might help